# Problema al comprar 2 valores

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, nosql, ejs

Estoy realizando el update de un registro, y hay un valor que se toma por un select, por lo que quiero que al momento de ingresar al registro a editar el mismo ya se encuentre seleccionado en el valor actual del registro, pero no me esta funcionando. Nose si es porque ambos valores son de tipo ObjetId o que.

```
<select required name="workSocial">
  <option value="" disabled  hidden>--</option>
  <% workSocials.forEach(workSocial=> { %>
    <option value="<%= workSocial._id %>" <%-workSocial._id===patient.workSocial  ? 'selected="selected"' : null%> ><%= workSocial.name %></option> 
  <% });%>
 </select>
```

Formato del registro patient

```
_id
62c07b9460d3b1d13af9e138
name
"dsakljd"
lastname
"kljdsalk"
dni
32183021
phone
"1902389012"
email
"jdksads@gmail.com"
number_affiliate
"ds9212"
date_birth
2016-02-11T00:00:00.000+00:00
workSocial
62b91ce0d8dcc54791bc7e9f

health_question
Array
createdAt
2022-07-02T17:08:36.607+00:00
updatedAt
2022-07-02T17:08:36.607+00:00
```

En ningun momento me escribe la propiedad selected

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El código debe ir en formato texto y no en imagen. Por favor haz clic en [edit] y realiza los cambios necesarios. Por otro lado, no es correcto comparar Objetos en Javascript. Lo suyo es comparar las representaciones de cadena de los mismos. En el caso de `ObjectId`, puedes obtener la representación de cadena con el método `toString`. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solucion fue la siguiente

```
<option value="<%= workSocial._id %>" <%= String(workSocial._id)===String(patient.workSocial)  ? 'selected="selected"' : null%> ><%= workSocial.name %></option>
```

Añadiendo String por delante de la variable.